# Delete previous item tableview Swift

Tags: swift, tableview, reloaddata

i'm facing a problem with one of my tableview, i decode JSON and put result in my cells, the problem is, each time i close the view and come back to it, previous items are still here :

[image: First time i enter in the view]

[image: Second time]

I think i have something to do with ReloadData, but i dont know what.

My Code :

```
//Retrieving JSON DATA : 

var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
            var DataFromJSon = jsonResult["objects"] as! NSArray
            for one in DataFromJSon {
                let repo = Repository(jsonData: one as! [String : AnyObject])
                repos.append(repo)

            }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as? UITableViewCell
    if (cell != nil)
    {   
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle,reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
    cell!.textLabel?.text =  repos[indexPath.row].title
    cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = repos[indexPath.row].price


    //on récupère l'url de l'image dans "Repository" et on la convertis en data exploitable
    let urlString: NSString = repos[indexPath.row].picture_url! ,
    imgURL = NSURL(string: urlString as String)

    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString as String) {
        // If this image is already cached, don't re-download
        if let img = imageCache[urlString as String] {
            cell!.imageView?.image = img
            cell!.imageView?.frame = CGRectMake(5,5,35,35)
            println("image présente")
        }
        else {
            // The image isn't cached, download the img data
            // We should perform this in a background thread
            let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL!)
            let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: mainQueue, completionHandler: { (response, data, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    // Convert the downloaded data in to a UIImage object
                    let image = UIImage(data: data)
                    // Store the image in to our cache
                    self.imageCache[urlString as String] = image
                    // Update the cell

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        if let cellToUpdate = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                            cellToUpdate.imageView?.image = image
                            cellToUpdate.imageView!.frame = CGRectMake(5,5,35,35)
                            println("image reload")
                        }
                    })
                }
                else {
                    println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            })
        }


    }
    return cell!
}
```

How can i solve this problem ?

Thank you !

Comment: Seems like you *append* the newly downlaoded data instead of rewriting the old data.

Comment: Maybe you need part of my code ?

Comment: It would clarify things, yes.

Comment: Look my updated post !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear previous repos before appending new items into the array.

```
var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
var DataFromJSon = jsonResult["objects"] as! NSArray

repos.removeAll() // clear old items.[Add this line of code]

for one in DataFromJSon {
    let repo = Repository(jsonData: one as! [String : AnyObject])
    repos.append(repo)

}
```